# Spring Batch with modular=true doesn't work for multiple jobs

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to configure two jobs with `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)`. This is to prevent naming clash as far as I understand.

Here's my job configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Dummy1 {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        // < build step. Omitted for code clarity > 
    }

    @Bean
    public Job getJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("dummy-job-1")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I have a similar class named `Dummy2`.

I also defined the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory getDummy1() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(Dummy1.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory getDummy2() {
        return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(Dummy2.class);
    }
}
```

When running the application I'm getting:

> The bean 'step', defined in class path resource
>   [~PATH~/Dumm2.class], could
>   not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in
>   class path resource
>   [~PATH~/Dumm1.class] and
>   overriding is disabled.

But I thought this is the all point of modular=true. That is, to handle names clashes.

On the other hand, if I'm enabling bean overriding I'm left with the second job overriding the first one.

i.e. `@Autowired List<Job>` has only one job (from `Dummy2.class`)

How to configure these jobs correctly?

Comment: Please share the code of `Dummy2` and the code you use to run your app. It would be better to share a repo with a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine. Thanks for the feedback. I uploaded a minimal project to this GitHub repo https://github.com/yaseco/spring-batch-multiple-modules

Comment: perfect thanks. I will take a look and get back to you (unless someone else answers your question in the meantime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@EnableBatchProcessing` is a Spring Batch annotation that pre-dates Spring Boot.  As such, you need to consider how it works within the context of Spring Boot.  I took a look at your sample application.  Let me first explain what is going wrong, then I'll explain how to fix it.

**The Problem**

When you configure `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)`, per the javadoc, you should have no `@Bean` definitions in the current context that you do not want to be bootstrapped.  Instead, you provide `ApplicationContextFactory` implementations as `@Bean`, each of which defines the child context for a job.

However, in your application there is a catch.  As noted, `@EnableBatchProcessing` pre-dates Spring Boot and as such you need to think about how it works within the context of Spring Boot.  In your case, the sample application has all the classes in the same package.  By default, Spring Boot will do a classpath scan for `@Configuration` annotated classes in the package that you define a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and "below".  So in your sample application, Spring Boot is bringing in `Dummy1` and `Dummy2` automatically into what should be the parent context causing your error.

**The Solution**

To fix this issue, you need to prevent Spring Boot from including your child context configurations with its classpath scanning.  To prove this, I tested your sample app by moving `Dummy1` and `Dummy2` to the package `com.example` (one level *above* the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`).  This prevented Spring Boot from picking them up with its classpath scanning and allowed the app to start correctly...with two other minor tweaks:

1. While the bean names can be duplicated in a modular configuration, the actual job names cannot.  In `Dummy1` and `Dummy2`, you configured both job names to be `dummy-job-1`.  Change one to be `dummy-job-2` and that addresses this issue.
2. Spring Boot requires a datasource for batch applications.  I added HSQLDB to the POM to prove out my fix and it worked.

With those changes, you will be able to build your application and run it via the command: `java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.batch.job.names=dummy-job-1` to run job 1 or `java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.batch.job.names=dummy-job-2` to run job 2.

There are many other ways to move the classes around to prevent Spring Boot's classpath scanning to pick them up and as long as Spring Boot doesn't pick up `Dummy1` and `Dummy2`, the app should work as you expect.  Good luck!

Comment: I created a pull request to your sample repository with my changes to demonstrate it working: https://github.com/yaseco/spring-batch-multiple-modules/pull/1

Comment: Michael, thank you so much for the detailed explanation and the pull request!! I had some guess that it might has something to do with Spring Boot actually.

Comment: If I may asking a following question; I still want to be able to control all the jobs at one place. For example, I'd like to have a `@Autowired List<Job> jobs` and to schedule tasks one by one. Or better yet, I'd like to have a `@RestController` that runs a job by name (by having a `@Autowired Map<String, Job> jobs`). How can I have this ability while still having `modular=true`?

Comment: I've made another commit do demonstrate the problem @ https://github.com/yaseco/spring-batch-multiple-modules

Comment: @yaseco Please open a new question for the follow up question.  I can take a look there.  Thanks!